# How to make an object to be a dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have implemented the below part of code :

```
array = [table.iloc[:, [0]], table.iloc[:, [i]]]
```

It is supposed to be a dataframe consisted of two vectors extracted from previously imported dataset. I use the parameter `i`, because this code is a part of a loop which uses a predefined function to analyze correlations between one fixed variable `[0]` and the rest of them - each iteration check a correlation with different variable `[i]`.

Python treats this object as a list or as a tuple when I change the brackets to round ones. I need this object to be a dataframe (next step is to remove NaN values using .dropna which is a df atribute.

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: A dataframe is an object of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library. You need to install the library, import it and use a dataframe constructor. It is not a native object in python. [Tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood your question, you want to build an extract from a larger dataframe containing only 2 columns known by their index number. You can simply do:

```
sub = table.iloc[:, [0,i]]
```

It will keep all attributes (including index, column names and dtype) from the original `table` dataframe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed the problem. However Python is still implying a set of errors, but the calculations are conducted completely, and the outcomes are correct.

Comment: @TomekZielonka: Please don't forget to accept one of the answers if the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal with the dataframe?

`dataframe` is a common term in data analysis using pandas

Pandas was developed just to facilitate such analysis, in it to get the data in a `.csv` file and transform into a dataframe is simple like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my-data.csv')
df.info()
```

Or from a dict or array

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict_or_array)
```

Then u can select the rows u wish

```
df.loc[:, ['INDEX_ROW_1', 'INDEX_ROW_2']]
```

Let us know if it's what you are looking for